# DFA for {w|w contains a substring of length at most 5 that has at least three 1's}

Tags: finite-automata

I have thought about this problem, but cannot come up with a convincing answer since I think this problem has too many states too consider. The accepting states can be length 5 substring and 3 1's, length 5 substring and 4 1's, length 5 substring and 3 1's, length 4 substring and 3 1's, length 4 subtring and 4 1's, length 3 substring and 3 1's. However, I am not sure how to think about this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are on the right track. Keep the last five bits seen in the state of the automaton. In fact you can start with 00000 rather than the empty string (no letters read), because it's the same count. Then, reading a 1 you move to 00001, etcetera.

Then note that any state which has (at least) three 1's is accepting, and whatever happens next the string will be accepted. So all these states can be lumped in to one accept state.

Now if my count is right you need 17 states.